# "Nested labels" in Highcharts

Tags: javascript, highcharts

Is there any way to have "nested labels" (for lack of a better term) on the xAxis in HighCharts? Attached is a picture of what I'm talking about. I've been going through the API but it doesn't seem entirely possible. I must be missing something. The idea here is that you have a main label range for the days of the month (lets say 1-31), then a label in the "center" beneath that for "March". Image is attached.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Take a look on this [Grouped categories plugin](http://www.highcharts.com/plugin-registry/single/11/Grouped-Categories).

After including `grouped-categories.js` and `styles.css`, adapt these code:

```
xAxis: {
        categories: [{
            name: "Fruit",
            categories: ["Apple", "Banana", "Orange"]
        }, {
            name: "Vegetable",
            categories: ["Carrot", "Potato", "Tomato"]
        }, {
            name: "Fish",
            categories: ["Cod", "Salmon", "Tuna"]
        }]
    }
```

Simple Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/TFhd7/

More usages and demos: https://github.com/blacklabel/grouped_categories/